# Symfony Entity Listener getEntityChangeSet Specific fields

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and I have an Entity Listener for check change on my entity User :

**services.yml**

```
    AppBundle\EventListener\EntityListener:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

**EntityListener**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

class EntityListener
{
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if (!$eventArgs->getEntity() instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        $changeArray = $eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet();

        var_dump($changeArray);
    }
}
```

So with this code, If I update my User with:

```
    $this->getUser()->setFirstname(uniqid());
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

the event preUpdate is triggered and I retrieve in `$changeArray` something like:

```
array(1) {
  ["firstname"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "5a5e1218c1026"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "5a5e123647f7d"
  }
}
```

So it's perfect, I get an array with old => new values, my question is:

How can I do if I want to exclude/include some fields? I don't want to listen and trigger preUpdate event on all my fields in `User`, but I don't want to check my `$changeArray`one by one (foreach => check the $key => if $key==xxxx...).

Any ideas? Maybe an annotation for that? A way to specify which fields I want to listen?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to exclude some fields from triggering lifecycle events while keeping the rest of doctrine's behaviour the same. If you have a look at Doctrine's `UnitOfWork`, you can see that [preUpdate events are dispatched for a specific class if an update is executed](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html#1031-1066) no matter the content of the change set.

Thus, if you want to exclude some fields, you actually have to filter them out by checking the content of the change set. `PreUpdateEventArgs` has a method named [`hasChangedField`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Event.PreUpdateEventArgs.html#_hasChangedField) to help you with that but you will still have to write the excluding/including condition yourself, in your listener.

---

That being said, you can prevent `preUpdate` from being triggered for certain fields by preventing updates from being triggered by those fields changes. If that's what you are after, you have to change the tracking policy of your entity and opt for the `NOTIFY` policy as explained [in the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your classname suggest `EntityListener` but you register it as `EventListener`. There is a difference between those.
Tag your `EntityListener` with `doctrine.orm.entity_listener` 
and change the `preUpdate` method to something like:

```
public function preUpdate($entity, PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
```

The final part is to [config you entity to use that entity listener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners).